# How can I remove html on line wrap?

Tags: html, css

Suppose you have:

```
<h1>800.BUY.WIDG &ndash; Call&nbsp;Now!</h1>
```

**But you want the `&ndash;` to appear only if the line *doesn't* wrap.**

I could do this:

```
<h1>800.BUY.WIDG</h1> <span class="stylistic_ndash">&ndash;</span> <h1>Call&nbsp;Now!</h1>
```

Then I could use media queries to remove the span element when the line would wrap.

The problem is that this approach quickly becomes untenable when there's several items like this on a page that each wrap at different viewport widths. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Edited the question so that my goal is bold.

Comment: You could do that with Javascript, but no way that you can do that with plain CSS.

Comment: I've already done it with plain CSS. I'm just seeking a more versatile solution that requires less maintenance.

Comment: Yes, you can do that just like you did with a span, but that's not an option for me. If you want to solve this in a proper way, you should use Javascript. What I actually want to know, is what you want to achieve by doing the thing you want. You want to overflow it, what?

Comment: The purpose of the ndash is to separate the content so it doesn't run together, a problem that is alleviated inherently upon line wrap. The above code is just one possible use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a weird solution, but you could possibly fake this behaviour using absolutely positioned dashes, and `overflow: hidden;` on the container.

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/e00hgrhb/1/

I've set the `h1` to be `overflow: hidden;` and then wrapped both items with a `span` element. Then this is the main styling to get it working:

```
h1 .item + .item {
    position: relative;
}
h1 .item + .item:before {
    content: "-";
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Any `.item` that follows another `.item` is set to `position: relative;` and it's `:before` pseudo-element is utilized to create the dash. I've positioned the dash using `right: 100%;` to make it sit entirely out of frame, to the left of the text. (I put a margin on it, as well as on every `.item` to allow the dash to have some space to breathe)

So what does this all do? Because the dash is absolutely positioned entirely outside of it's containing `.item`, it doesn't take up any space in the flow, so when the container gets too small to fit both items, the left edge of the text stays butted up against the left edge of the container. This means the dash is now also entirely outside of the `h1` element.

Because the overflow of the `h1` is being hidden, the dash appears to no longer be there.

---

Is is the best solution? I don't know... beauty is in the eye of the beholder on this one. But it is *a* solution, and one that doesn't require a bunch of javascript to make a relatively small change.

---

**edit:** I had to add `display: inline-block;` to the `.item` class to get this to work in firefox